# C# WPF XamDataGrid How to get Total of a Field and put it into textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, sum, xamdatagrid

How can i get the total of a field in a XamDataGrid?  I want to show the sum of all records' $ amounts in a textbox NOT in the grid itself.  Here's how i did this for the number of items in the grid, which works:

```
<Label Content="Total Line Items"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=xamDataGrid1, Path=Records.Count, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1" />
```

So how can i sum a certain field?  Is it possible to do anything like:

```
        <Label Content="Total Salaries: " Grid.Column="2" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="Red" Text="{Binding ElementName=xamDataGrid1, Path=**SUM(SALARYFIELD)**, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

I do not want the SummaryDefintions method (I know how to do that already) and i must not refer to the grid in code-behind etc.  What can i put in the binding, or what can i replace SUM(SALARYFIELD) with to make this work?

Comment: Can you not expose a property in your ViewModel that sums up certain fields you need to show in the UI?

Comment: i could but would rather just do it in the xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer i was looking for.  Had to involve XamDataGrid's Summary definitions, but I can not show them and then bind to their data as below:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=xamDataGrid1, Path=Records.SummaryResults[1].Value, StringFormat=C, Mode=OneWay}"
```